# Plot an integral with different parameters

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, legending

I got an issue of plotting an integral with different parameters 'j',such as 'j' is from 0.1 to 0.9 , I want the final graph to include all the j constants and to be labeled too.

````
  ```h[k_]={{352 (4 - Sqrt[3]/2) (1 - j) j + 4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j) + 24 j^2 (2 - 1.01 Cos[k/2]^2), 0. - 4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j), 0.,  0.}, {0. - 4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j),  352 (4 - Sqrt[3]/2) (1 - j) j + 4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j) +  8 (315 j^2 + 100 Sqrt[3] (1 - j) j Cos[k/2]) +  24 j^2 (2 - 1.01 Cos[k/2]^2), 0. - 4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j), 0.}, {0., 0. - 4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j),  352 (4 - Sqrt[3]/2) (1 - j) j + 4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j) +   8 (315 j^2 + 100 Sqrt[3] (1 - j) j Cos[k/2]) + 24 j^2 (2 - 1.01 Cos[k/2]^2), 0. - 4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j)}, {0., 0., 0. - 4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j),   352 (4 - Sqrt[3]/2) (1 - j) j + 4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j) + 24 j^2 (2 - 1.01 Cos[k/2]^2)}}
````

```
n = 4;s=1;

g[k_] := Tr[Eigenvalues[h[k]]];

f[t_?NumericQ] := 
  n Pi NIntegrate[1/(Exp[g[k]/t] - 1), {k, 0, n Pi}, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 4];

Plot[1 - 1/(s n) 1/(2*Pi)^2*f[t], {t, .001, 3000}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Black,
 ImageSize -> Full, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 FrameLabel -> {"T(K)", "<\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(z\)]\)>"}]
```

Comment: The integrand in `f` gives non numeric values. Fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
```

Make all of the arguments explict.

[`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) and [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) `h`

```
h[j_, k_] = {{352 (4 - Sqrt[3]/2) (1 - j) j + 
       4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j) + 24 j^2 (2 - 1.01 Cos[k/2]^2), 
      0. - 4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j), 0., 
      0.}, {0. - 4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j), 
      352 (4 - Sqrt[3]/2) (1 - j) j + 4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j) + 
       8 (315 j^2 + 100 Sqrt[3] (1 - j) j Cos[k/2]) + 
       24 j^2 (2 - 1.01 Cos[k/2]^2), 0. - 4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j), 
      0.}, {0., 0. - 4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j), 
      352 (4 - Sqrt[3]/2) (1 - j) j + 4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j) + 
       8 (315 j^2 + 100 Sqrt[3] (1 - j) j Cos[k/2]) + 
       24 j^2 (2 - 1.01 Cos[k/2]^2), 
      0. - 4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j)}, {0., 0., 
      0. - 4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j), 
      352 (4 - Sqrt[3]/2) (1 - j) j + 4 (315 j + 400 (1 - j) j) + 
       24 j^2 (2 - 1.01 Cos[k/2]^2)}} //
    Rationalize // Simplify;

n = 4; s = 1;
```

`Simplify` `g`

```
g[j_, k_] = Tr[Eigenvalues[h[j, k]]] // Simplify

(* -(4/25) j (-106700 + 4400 Sqrt[3] + 42803 j - 4400 Sqrt[3] j + 
   10000 Sqrt[3] (-1 + j) Cos[k/2] + 303 j Cos[k]) *)

f[j_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] :=
  n Pi NIntegrate[1/(Exp[g[j, k]/t] - 1), {k, 0, n Pi},
    AccuracyGoal -> 4,
    PrecisionGoal -> 4];

Plot[
 Evaluate[
  Table[1 - 1/(s n) 1/(2*Pi)^2*f[j, t],
   {j, 1/10, 9/10, 1/10}]],
 {t, 1/1000, 3000},
 Frame -> True,
 ImageSize -> Medium,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 FrameLabel -> {"T(K)",
   "<\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(z\)]\)>"},
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[
   Range[0.1, 0.9, 0.1],
   LegendLabel -> j]]
```

[image]